# Who are Saptamatrikas?

Tags: tantra, shaktism, matrika

Who are Saptamatrikas? Where we can find the first reference of Saptamatrikas in our scripture? What is the significance of Saptamatrika worship? Please provide references directly from primary sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Who are the Saptamātṛkā or Saptamātṛ?

> [Chapter 54](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manasara-english-translation/d/doc421102.html), Mānasāra śilpaśastra
>
> [शक्तिलक्षणम्](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.22948/page/n395/mode/1up?view=theater)
>
> वाराही चैव कौमारी चामुण्डी भैरवी तथा । 
> माहेन्द्री वैष्णवी चैव ब्रहामी सप्तमातरः ॥
>
> > 126-127. Vārāhī, Kaumārī, Cāmuṇḍī, Bhairavī, Māhendrī, Vaiṣṇavī and
> > Brahmāṇī: these are the seven mother goddesses.
>
> English Translation by Prasanna Kumar Acharya

#### The Description of the Saptamātṛkā goddesses.

Mānasāra describes that too.

> 134. Vārāhī should have a face like the snout of a hog, and should put on the kirīṭa type of crown.
> 135. Kaumārī should put on the karaṇḍa type of crown, and Vaiṣṇavī the kirīṭa crown.
> 136. Cāmuṇḍī should put on the jaṭā type of crown, and Bhairavī a prominent alaka type of crown.
> 137. & 138. The two upper and lower right bands should hold the pike and
>      the wind-followers respectively; the upper of the other (left) two
>      hands should hold up the skull and the other hand the net.
> 138. Both Cāmaṇḍī and Bhairavī should similarly hold up an arrow.
> 139. Cāmuṇḍī should have a dark-bluish complexion, and Bhairavī a red complexion.
> 140. to 142. According to some, the two upper hands of Bhairavī should be
>      in the boon-giving and refuge-offering postures; and the other right
>      and left hands should hold up a pike and a drum respectively.
> 141. She should be clad in a red garment, and the two breasts on the sides should be covered with red bodices.
> 142. Cāmuṇḍī should put on a garland on the head, and be adorned with all ornaments.
> 143. Bhairavī should be clad in dark (black) clothes, and have long and dark locks of hair.
> 144. Both Vaiṣṇavī and Vārāhī should have a bright blue complexion.
>
> ....
>
> 149. to 150. She should be clad in reddish yellow clothes, and should be
>      adorned with all ornaments; thus is described Vaiṣṇavī.
> 150. to 152. Vārāhī should hold the plough with the (lower) right hand;
>      her upper left hand should hold the net and the (upper) right hand
>      should be in the refuge-offering posture, and the (other) left hand in
>      the boon-giving posture; and she should be adorned with all ornaments.
> 151. She should be clad in yellow clothes; Kaumārī should have a red complexion.
> 152. to 165. The two right hands should be in the boon-giving and the
>      refuge-offering postures, and the left hands should be placed as if on
>      the door (?); there should be a skull in the right hand and missiles
>      in the two left hands.
> 153. to 157. She should be clad in bright blue clothes, and adorned with
>      all ornaments; thus are described the features of Kaumārī.
> 154. to 159. Brahmāṇī should have four faces; the two loft hands should be
>      in the boon-giving and the refuge-offering postures; and a pot and a
>      rosary garland should be held in the two upper right hands
>      respectively.
> 155. to 161. She should be clad in pure red clothes, and adorned with all
>      ornaments; thus is described Brahmāṇī.
> 156. to 163. Rudrāṇī should have a white complexion; her two upper right
>      and left hands should be in the boon-giving and refuge-offering
>      postures (respectively); the deer should be in the other left hand and
>      the net in the other right hand.
> 157. She should be clad in leather (skin) clothes, and adorned with all ornaments.
> 158. to 166. The conch leaf (śaṅkhapatra) should be put on the left ear
>      and earring on the right: thus are described the features of Rudrāṇī.
> 159. to 167. Cāmuṇḍī should put on a coach leaf (śaṅhkapatra) on the left
>      ear and a conch earring on the right.
> 160. All other goddesses should be adorned with crocodile-shape earring on the ears.

#### The Origin:

It **maybe** related to a story found in various Purāṇas, including the Vāmana Purāṇa

> [Chapter 29 to 30](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.313087/page/280/mode/1up?view=theater).
>
> - After having slain Canda & Munda, the demon Raktabija came forth with a large army seeing which goddess Candika made a huge ware cry,
>   and thus from her mouth manifested goddess Brahmāṇī seated on a
>   swan-driven chariot holding a rosary and kamndalu in her hands.
> - Then manifested the three-eyed fierce goddess Māhesvari seated on a bull, holding a trident, wearing bracelets and earrings of snakes.
> - From the throat of Candika, manifested goddess Kaumārī, with peacock's feather, holding a lance in her hand, seated on a peacock.
> - From the arms of Candika manifested, the great energy of god Visnu, goddess Vaiṣṇavī, seated on the Garuda, holding conch, discus,
>   sword and the Saranga bow, and arrows in her hands.
> - From the back side of Candika manifested, goddess Vārāhī, arned with a dreadful mace, scratching the Earth with her teeths, seated on
>   the serpent Sesa.
> - From the breast regions of Candika manifested goddess Māhendrī holding a thunderbolt and a goad, decorated with various ornaments,
>   seated on an elephant.
> - From the chest region manifested goddess Nārsimhī, with fierce claws and nails, scattering about planets and stars with movement of
>   her mane.

- However, note that we do not find a mention of goddess Bhairavī.
- Similar story is found in the [Devī-māhātmya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117167.html) of the Mārkaṇḍeya Purāṇa, although in this version the goddess manifests from the bodies of different male gods.

Comment: I found this [article-cum-blog](https://sreenivasaraos.com/2012/10/06/saptamatrka-part-one-devi/) which discusses in detail about the Saptamātṛkās with elaborate references from several perspectives. But, due to its third party and blog like nature I have omitted using it in the answer. Hope this helps too